# hls js get stream title from metadata

Tags: http-live-streaming, hls.js

I am using hls js for radio playback. This works well. My question is is there a way to retrive currently playing song data (title, artist)?  I tried using some callbacks like (MANIFEST_PARSED, MANIFEST_LOADED) but no success finding this information.

```
var audio = document.querySelector('#audio');
var url = 'https://stream.ram.radio/audio/ram.stream_aac/playlist.m3u8'

if (Hls.isSupported()) {
   var hls = new Hls();
   hls.attachMedia(audio);

    hls.on(Hls.Events.MEDIA_ATTACHED, function () {
        hls.loadSource(url);
    });

    hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, function (event, data) {
        console.log(data)

   });         

    hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_LOADED, function (event, data) {
        console.log(data)
    });
}

  <audio preload="true" id="audio" controls crossorigin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

*edit: referencing the docs here: https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/blob/master/docs/API.md -- This event should be fired when the id3 tags are parsed.

```
hls.on(Hls.Events.FRAG_PARSING_METADATA, function(event, data) {
  if (data) {
    console.log("Data", data);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge HLS streams don’t include such information.

Here’s a typical HLS data header (this one for “Skate Phantom”) under:

```
https://sample.vodobox.net/skate_phantom_flex_4k/skate_phantom_flex_4k.m3u8
```

Header follows…

```
#EXTM3U 
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=288000,RESOLUTION=256x144 low/skate_phantom_flex_4k_228_144p.m3u8 
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=582000,RESOLUTION=426x240 medium/skate_phantom_flex_4k_452_240p.m3u8 
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1018000,RESOLUTION=640x360 high/skate_phantom_flex_4k_788_360p.m3u8 
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1366000,RESOLUTION=854x480 veryhigh/skate_phantom_flex_4k_1056_480p.m3u8 
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=2742000,CODECS="avc1.4d001f,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=1280x720 hdready/skate_phantom_flex_4k_2112_720p.m3u8 
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=5400000,CODECS="avc1.640028,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=1920x1080 fullhd/skate_phantom_flex_4k_4160_1080p.m3u8 
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=7556000,CODECS="avc1.640028,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=2560x1440 2k/skate_phantom_flex_4k_5816_1440p.m3u8 
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=10768000,CODECS="avc1.640028,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=3840x2160 4k/skate_phantom_flex_4k_8288_2160p.m3u8
```

As can be seen it gives you all available resolutions for your media player to switch to but there’s no info on what is actually playing.

Our only option is to go by the “file name” extracted from the URL which reduces to… “skate_phantom_...”

Btw, I use the same library as you.